# What happen if chunk size goes beyond the limit[64 mb] for single shard key in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, sharding, chunks

We have a sharded cluster of mongodb. shard key is sellerId. We have nearly 20k sellers. We capture responses for sellers. Some sellers may have huge response set. Now lets say sellerId 10001 has some very good listing and got millions of responses in that case single shard key 10001 has huge data and goes beyond of 64 mb of default size. As per mongo documentation there can be only one chunk per shard key in res in replica set. What will happen with this chunk. Does the chunk size automatically increase?

Comment: It will become a [Jumbo Chunk](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/sharding-data-partitioning/#jumbo-chunk). Avoid it at any cost. Change shard key. Choose one based on [cardinality, frequency, and rate of change](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/sharding-shard-key/#choosing-a-shard-key).

Comment: I understand that it will lead to shard imbalance, but how will hit performance

Comment: imbalance = one shard is loaded more than others. You cannot scale it horizontally, and may experience significant drop in performance under load when resources of the affected shard are fully utilised.